# How to access a contributed module Information from drupal.org

Tags: 7, community-official-site

1. Is there any API to access Information about a contributed module
   from drupal.org site?
2. How does Update Manager access information
   from drupal.org?

By finding this I think I too could access other data similarly and I also need **Hook API documents** to be accessed from drupal.org in my site.

*Did anyone do this before? If so please guide me.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An update URL is formatted as:

```
http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/[project-name]/[api-version]
```

So for Views v7, for example, that would be:

```
http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/views/7.x
```

I think that's as much information as Drupal.org makes available about modules via its API. You won't find a structured way to query information about hooks, for the same reasons we talked about in [your similar recent question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/154123/get-a-particular-modules-information-programmatically)